# Column default value in mysql tables changes while exporting mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am exporting mysql table for backup, but while exporting DB I noticed that my column default value is changing. If it was "100" earlier then after export it is now changed to "none",

Comment: Please add relevant code. How are you exporting? A `select` wouldn't change data, nor would `mysqldump`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have 100 in the default, i suggest you to do

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
    ALTER COLUMN column_name int DEFAULT 100;
```

and then export again.

Comment: If that doesn't work, then you have to share the PHP code you're using.